# Are there classes of non-linear programs that always have sparse solutions?

Tags: nonlinear-programming

It is well-known that linear programs always have sparse solutions -- solutions in which only at most $m$ variables are nonzero, where $m$ is the number of constraints.

In [the answers to this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/11409/2576), it is shown that the same does not hold for quadratic convex programs, as there may be quadratic programs in which all solutions are dense.

QUESTION: are there other classes of mathematical programs (besides linear programs) in which all problems are guaranteed to have sparse solutions?

Comment: Just to be clear, LPs do not always have sparse solutions out of the box. If an LP has nontrivial lower bounds for the variables, you can convert it to one with a sparse solution by replacing $x \ge \ell$ with $x'=x-\ell \ge 0.$ So I guess you would be looking for other model classes easily convertible to equivalent models with sparse solutions.

Comment: @prubin yes, this is what I meant